# Using another column as reference in conditional formatting.

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting, vba

I want to use conditional formatting using another column as a reference.
Lets lock for this example

```
A              | B   
cat.12.30.dog  | cat
cow.3.cat      | dog
cat.bus        | truck
car.truck      |
bus.dog.cat    |
truck          |
dog            |
```

So I want to highlight cells in column A which begins with any word from column B
therefor as a result of what I mean in the example I should get those cells highlighted

```
cat.12.30.dog 
cat.bus
truck
dog
```

I have tried (=SUM) but it didn't work as I want, So I am asking for any way to do this task

Best regards

Comment: @pnuts: I'd be more interested in finding out what he was thinking of while using `SUM`. :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this formula:

```
=NOT(ISERROR(MATCH(1,IF(ISERROR(SEARCH($B$1:$B$3,A1)),0,SEARCH($B$1:$B$3,A1)),0)))
```

The result will be like this:

[image]

Make sure you do not have trailing/leading spaces.
Hope this helps.